# How to convert a string "x" to the variable x in Python?

Tags: python, parsing

I receive three strings from the user.

```
P=...
Q=...
R=...
```

They can include, x, y, z and operators +, - , *, ^, /

I want to form a list, `F=[P, Q, R]` For example, if user had given P = x, Q = y, R = z, the corresponding list would be F=[x,y,z].
I would receive them as strings

```
P="x"
Q="y"
R="z"
```

Now how to create F as mentioned before and not as a list of strings?

Comment: So you don't want them as strings, that's fine. But do the names `x`/`y`/`z` already defined and refer to some objects in the current namespace?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. `x`, `y` and `z` would be the names of variables that are already defined? I don't understand your question, but maybe you want to have a look at sympy: https://scipy-lectures.org/packages/sympy.html

Comment: you want to add the three strings to a list but not as a list of strings?

Comment: Can you read your question again? I dont understand anything. Read this please https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
P, Q, R = "x", "y", "z"
x, y, z = 1, 2, 3
F=[eval(P), eval(Q), eval(R)] #evals to [1, 2, 3]
```

works if you already have variables defined with the correct names.

However note that, as mentioned in comments and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) for example, this is bad practice:

> 1. There is almost always a better way to do it
> 2. Very dangerous and insecure
> 3. Makes debugging difficult
> 4. Slow

There are safer alternatives as @anentropic suggests, like [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Comment: Note that calling `eval()` on any user input is considered dangerous.

Comment: safer is https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval